# not able to Implement Scrollview(scrolling and zooming) for Gallery View

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Am using scrollView to implement Gallery like View. But i am stuck. I have dynamic, say 10 pics to be shown in the horizontal scroller, once at a time. am using following code

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    UIImageView *img1=[array_for_ImageView objectAtIndex:currentImageView];
    return img1;
}
```

problem is, it works fine for the first ImageView. But creates a huge rendering problem when trying to zoom the image at 2, 3 etc vertex. I want to implement scrolling and zooming both.

I also used

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
```

to check when the zooming end so that I can reset UIscrollView size again.
Please guide me.

[image: First image before scrolling]

[image: First image after scrolling]

[image: Here I tried to zoom the third image and its gone!!]

Comment: bro set maxzoomscale to change the size

Comment: @Yohan
I have already done that. using scrollView_Mag.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;

and its zooming. but there's no sync between zooming and scrolling at the same time

Comment: syn means could you show any screen shot?? cant get exactly

Comment: @Yohan I have added some Images for the same. in third images i was tring to zoom my third image, and no idea where my third image is

Comment: k try to set  self.scrollView.zoomScale=1.0; to default wen you scrollViewDidEndZooming is over

Comment: refer this example project https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fgallery

Comment: @NANNAV I checked it, It too having some issues, not perfect